# Adjoint of Translation Functors in Category O

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

> Let $\mu,\lambda\in\mathfrak{h}^*$ with $\mu-\lambda\in \Lambda$ and let $pr_\mu$ and $pr_\lambda$ be natural projections of category $O$ onto blocks $O_{\chi_\mu}$ and $O_{\chi_\lambda}$ respectively.  Now the $W-$orbit of $\gamma:=\mu-\lambda$ contains a unique weight $\bar{\gamma}\in \Lambda^+$.  Set $L:=L(\bar{\gamma})$ and let $T_\lambda^\mu$ be the translation functor be as follows:
> For $M\in O$, $T_\lambda^\mu$ sends $M$ to $pr_\mu(L\otimes(pr_\lambda M))$, followed by inclusion into O.

**My question is**: How to show that $Hom_O(T_\lambda^\mu M,N)\simeq Hom_O(M,T_\mu^\lambda N)$?

I can prove that $T_\mu^\lambda N=pr_\lambda(L^*\otimes(pr_\mu N))$ where $L$ is the dual of $L$.

I think I need to use the isomorphism $Hom_O(L\otimes M,N)\simeq Hom_O(M, L^*\otimes N)$.  But I do not know how to deal with the projection part.

Comment: It's been a long while (very long) since I last thought about such things. But, don't the projections to various blocks simply write *any* module as a direct sum submodules each in their block? Then you could use the fact that $Hom$ is additive (and that there are no non-zero homomorphism between modules in different blocks).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, but I do not know how to decompose a module into blocks after tensoring with a finitely dimensional module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are no non-zero homomorphisms between modules in distinct blocks and all the modules $M$ have the projection $pr_\mu M$ as a direct summand, we also have the following isomorphisms for all $\mu, M,N$:
$$
Hom(pr_\mu M,N)\simeq Hom(pr_\mu M,pr_\mu N)\simeq Hom(M,pr_\mu N).
$$
Using these in addition to the natural isomorphism you described it becomes simple:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Hom(T^\mu_\lambda M,N)&=Hom(pr_\mu(L\otimes pr_\lambda M),N)\\
&\simeq Hom(pr_\mu(L\otimes pr_\lambda M),pr_\mu N)\\
&\simeq Hom(L\otimes pr_\lambda M, pr_\mu N)\\
&\simeq Hom(pr_\lambda M, L^*\otimes pr_\mu N)\\
&\simeq Hom(pr_\lambda M, pr_\lambda(L^*\otimes pr_\mu N))\\
&\simeq Hom(M,pr_\lambda(L^*\otimes pr_\mu N))\\
&= Hom(M,T^\lambda_\mu N).
\end{aligned}
$$